# Cascading list boxes

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have searched on several pages and have found a couple of articles on the subject but I still can't seem to know what is missing. 
My code shows just the entries for the first list box. When I click it, I get the data out of database however, nothing is shown in the second list box. (Btw. I use PRISM framework). Could someone give me a hint?

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}" SelectedValue="ID" DisplayMemberPath="BEZ" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FoodList}" DisplayMemberPath="BEZ"/>
```

My view model:

```
public class FoodViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private FOODGROUP _selectedGroup;
    public FOODGROUP SelectedGroup
    {
        get { return this._selectedGroup; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this._selectedGroup, value);
            GetFoodByGroup(SelectedGroup.ID);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FOODGROUP> GroupList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FOOD> FoodList{ get; set; }

    public FoodViewModel()
    {
        GroupList = new ObservableCollection<FOODGROUP>(FoodController.GetGroups());
    }

    private void GetFoodByGroup(long groupId)
    {
        FoodList = new ObservableCollection<FOOD>(FoodController.GetFoodList(groupId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
public ObservableCollection<FOOD> FoodList{ get; set; }
```

By this

```
private ObservableCollection<FOOD> _foodList;
public ObservableCollection<FOOD> FoodList
{
    get 
    { 
        return _foodList;
    }
    set
    { 
        SetProperty(ref this._foodList, value);
    } 
}
```